# Comparing Old and New Billing Address on Account in a trigger

Tags: apex

What are the ways the old billing address can be compared with the new billing address (in a trigger)?

**Billing address comparison below**

```
    for(Account a:trigger.new)
    {
        if(a.BillingAddress  != trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).BillingAddress){

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use comparison operators == or != on the individual components of the billing address? Can you please expand your question with a bit more detail, formula, trigger, controller, etc.

Comment: @Eric - I am writing a trigger where comparison for old and new address is required.

Comment: Please post what you have so far. It is basically using the comparison operators and trigger.new compared to trigger.old values. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Eric - I have added the comparison lines above.

Comment: @xyzsfdc what is your question then? Your above code seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to compare individual field for comparison. Some thing like

Complete compound fields

> BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState,
>   BillingPostalCode,BillingCountry, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude

Now your code will look like

```
for(Account a:trigger.new)
    {
        if(a.BillingStreet != trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).BillingStreet || a.BillingCity!= trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).BillingCity){
                // Perform some action address is not same
                // Add all fields same as above
        }
    }
```