# trigger to update contact when account is updated

Tags: apex, after-trigger

```java
trigger AcccAddrUpdate on Account (after update) { 
    if (trigger.isafter && trigger.isUpdate){
        List<contact> conNList = new List<contact>();
        for(Account accRecn :trigger.New){
            Account accReco = trigger.OldMap.get(accRecn.Id);
            if(accRecn.ShippingAddress != accReco.ShippingAddress){
                contact conN = new contact();
                conN.AccountId = accRecn.Id;
                conN.FirstName = accRecn.name;
                conN.LastName = 'test contact';
                conN.MailingStreet = accRecn.ShippingStreet;
                conN.MailingCity = accRecn.ShippingCity;
                conN.MailingState = accRecn.ShippingState;
                conN.MailingPostalCode = accRecn.ShippingPostalCode;
                conNList.add(conN);
             }
        }

        upsert conNList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, you have a statement and some code, but you haven't asked a question. You need to [edit] your question to tell us what your question is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suspect the issue is you are comparing a compound field - see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94925/comparing-old-and-new-billing-address-on-account-in-a-trigger

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger isn't updating the contact but is create a new contact, where the Shipping address is changing for the account.

Hence :

1. Firstly you need to use Upsert or Insert instead for update as this new contact is not present in salesforce.
2. If you need to update the existing contacts of the account then you need to query the all the contacts for that particular account using SOQL, then iterate over contact list and at the end update the list back in Salesforce.

Comment: I neeed to insert a new contact as the account shiipping addresss changes

Comment: okay thanks vasu